# Pre-built directives for D3 in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I found few documents on how to integrate Angular with D3 by building D3 Directives. I was wondering how come I can't find these D3 directives ready? I would expect that same as we have these D3 js files we will have a "library" of these directives for everyone to use and not build one every-time. 
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I get your question but...are you asking us how you can integrate D3 inside angular directives? There's no black magic around that...D3 is just like any other library you would integrate inside a directive. Apparently you already found articles on how to do that.

If your problem is not having a good source of D3 directives for angular, well...I smell opportunity and I would start my own project on github or contribute to the already existing projects. Namely:

https://github.com/robinboehm/angular-d3-directives

https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives

Comment: And yet another one: [https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3).